# SSRS - Count blank cells in tablix column grouping?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I'm trying to find a way of counting the blank cells that appear only in a column grouping in a table (and not the dataset itself), unfortunately I can't find a way of doing so.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

I tried creating a sample report based on your requirement .. I am able to count the empty cell but the point is the location where you want to display this information ...

Let me explain, how i tried to achieve this

1. written a code  custom code

   ```
   Dim CntEmpty AS INTEGER=0
   Public Function CountCell(SalesValue AS INTEGER,Flag AS Boolean) AS INTEGER
   IF (SalesValue <=0) THEN 
       CntEmpty =CntEmpty +1

   IF(Flag) THEN
    RETURN CntEmpty    
   ELSE    
    RETURN 0 
   END IF

   ELSE
       RETURN SalesValue 
   END IF

   END FUNCTION
   ```
2. Calling a function on Cell Value (write expression)

[image]

3. Output

[image]

Try follow above step, hopefully that will give some idea

Comment: Thank you for this, unfortunately I couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score -1):

In the expression subtract the rows that have data from a column that has data in all columns(I.E your primary column)

```
=Count(Fields!PrimaryKey.Value) - Count(Fields!FieldContainingBlanks.Value)
```